# Rails route parent ID name and CanCan issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, cancan

I'm trying to get a simple route working

```
/agenda_items/5/feed
```

To do this, I have the following route setup

```
resources :agenda_items do
  member do
   get "/feed", to: "comments#feed"
  end
end
```

In each of my controllers, I'm using CanCan to handle the authentication and it works fine, however on this one action I'm having an issue, which I'm pretty sure is down to rails`naming generation. When I run`rake routes`, the route above is produced as

```
feed_agenda_item        /agenda_items/:id/feed(.:format)                     agenda_items/:id#feed
```

As far as I can tell, CanCan is expecting the `:id` parameter, to actually be `:agenda_item_id` so as a result, my parent resource isn't being loaded.

Is there any way I can get rails to change this so that CanCan will work without me having to manually load and authorize the resource, or is there a way I can get CanCan to change what it's looking for on certain actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your routes are wrong. You try to create a member action for `agenda items` which routes to the `comments` controller. If you want a feed of all the commments from a single agenda item you should do something like this:

```
resources :agenda_items do
  resources :comments do
    collection do
      get :feed
    end
  end
end
```

You should now get the following when running `rake routes`:

```
feed_agenda_item_comments      /agenda_items/:agenda_item_id/feed(.:format)                     comments#feed
```

Comment: That's what I've changed it to now. I was hoping to use the route in agenda_items but this will do :)

Comment: You could move the feed action from comments to agenda items controller, and then have the routes as before :)

Comment: yeah I know. I'm just trying to be awkward :P Basically the feed applies to an agenda item (like comments) but it technically consists of comment resources. This way works though so it's fine :)